# Compare previous data rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

Fairly new to this and I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have done research on this in different forums but it seems like I cannot find an answer to my question.  It seems like a straightforward query (I have tried temp variable to update, LAG, CTE...etc) but I just cannot get it to work.  Any help is appreciated as I have been stuck for days now.

There is already a source data table (emp, hourly, date, and seq) with all the essential data in it.  I just need to create 3 new columns, "last change date", "last change seq" and "previous hourly", and insert those data values into those 3 new columns in each existing row except the earliest row.  So for the 3/5/2017 row, I'd like to see "last change date" as 6/5/2016, "last change seq" is 1, and "previous hourly" of 45.55, for the 6/6/2016 row, "last change date" would be 1/10/2016, "last change seq" is 0, and "previous hourly" would be 42.37...etc

```
DECLARE @hrly_chg TABLE([emp] char(1),[hourly] numeric (15, 6), [date] DATETIME, [seq] INT);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A', 46.23,'03/05/2017',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',45.55,'6/6/2016',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',45.55,'6/5/2016',1);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',42.37,'6/5/2016',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',42.37,'1/10/2016',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',41.54,'8/16/2015',1);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',38.33,'8/16/2015',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',38.33,'2/8/2015',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',38.33,'1/20/2015',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'1/10/2015',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'1/9/2015',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'1/8/2015',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'12/14/2014',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'8/19/2014',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'8/19/2014',1);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',26.73,'1/1/2014',0);    
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',25.22,'8/19/2013',0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: The order would be order by date and seq

Edit 2 (desirable output in jpeg):
[Hourly rate change output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzyVB.jpg)

Comment: Can you please put your sample output in a nice tabular format so that we can discuss it?

Comment: And a question: what is the order applied to the input records by which you define the previous row?

Comment: I have added 2 edits.  The data should be sorted by date, then seq, and that is how a "previous" row is defined.  I have also attached a jpeg on what the desirable output should be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

http://rextester.com/UILB97912

Since you mentioned the LAG function, that is the easiest way to accomplish this.

```
select @@version as 'sql server version'


DECLARE @hrly_chg TABLE([emp] char(1),[hourly] numeric (15, 6), [date] DATETIME, [seq] INT);

INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A', 46.23,'03/05/2017',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',45.55,'6/6/2016',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',45.55,'6/5/2016',1);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',42.37,'6/5/2016',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',42.37,'1/10/2016',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',41.54,'8/16/2015',1);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',38.33,'8/16/2015',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',38.33,'2/8/2015',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',38.33,'1/20/2015',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'1/10/2015',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'1/9/2015',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'1/8/2015',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'12/14/2014',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'8/19/2014',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',31.20,'8/19/2014',1);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',26.73,'1/1/2014',0);
INSERT INTO @hrly_chg VALUES ('A',25.22,'8/19/2013',0);

declare @HourlyNew table ([emp] char(1),[hourly] numeric (15, 6), [date] DATETIME, [seq] INT,[LastChangeDate] datetime, LastChangeSEQ INT,[PreviousHourly] numeric(15,6))

insert into @HourlyNew (Emp,Hourly,Date,Seq)
select * from @Hrly_Chg

select h.emp,h.hourly,h.date,h.seq
,LAG(Date, 1,1) OVER (partition by emp ORDER BY date ,seq desc) AS PreviousDate 
,LAG(Seq, 1,1) OVER (partition by emp ORDER BY date ,seq desc) AS PreviousSeq 
,LAG(hourly, 1,1) OVER (partition by emp ORDER BY date ,seq desc) AS PreviousHourly  

from @HourlyNew h
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I see you opted for an `order by date, seq **desc**` clause. Isn't it somewhat counter-intuitive?

Comment: This is true. The idea is to get the highest SEQ number, so if you have multiple records with the same date, the LAG function should grab the highest (most recently inserted) record. The OP may have to adjust the code to suit his specific application, but this is the general idea.

Comment: I am probably missing something... Doesn't `order by seq desc` mean that the LAG function will fetch the lowest, not the highest value?

Comment: Aron, thanks for this.  I have done a similar run but it did not give me desirable results because there could be multiple rows in the same date (distinguish by a different seq#, so emp + date + seq are unique identifier), and LAG does not lookup the "real" previous row.  I have added a jpeg to show the desirable output.

Comment: In that case, add those columns to your lag partition `,LAG(Date, 1,1) OVER (partition by emp,date,seq ORDER BY date ,seq desc) AS PreviousDate ` I don't use LAG often, so you may have to play around with it, but it can definitely be done. The other option is a messy one -- you have to use sub queries and it's much more complex. let me know if you can't get lag to work though

Answer (score 0):

This returns the desired result set using your example data setup.  This does not need to use any CTE, I just found it easier to follow.

I didn't under stand if you need to update existing values in a table from your question, or if you only need to return output that matches your attachment.

If you need to insert or update records in an existing table, this will get you almost all the way there.  Try putting the final query here into another CTE or temp table and `merge` into your existing table to perform a upsert.

The first CTE gets records where `hourly` changed.  In the second CTE, we add previous and next changed values.

Or final query brings it all together to produce our output.

**Query**

```
-- get hourly change dates
;with setup as (
select  hr.emp,
        hr.seq,
        hr.hourly,          
        case when hr.hourly != lag(hr.hourly,1,1) over (partition by hr.emp order by date asc, hr.seq asc) 
            or row_number() over (partition by hr.emp order by hr.date asc, hr.seq asc) = 1 -- first row can't lag
                then hr.[date]
                else null
        end ChangedDate
from @hrly_chg hr
)
-- add previous and next change date & hourly
, setup2 as
(
    select  s1.emp,
            s1.ChangedDate,
            s1.seq,
            s1.hourly as NewHourly,
            lag(s1.Hourly, 1, null) over (partition by s1.emp order by s1.ChangedDate asc, s1.seq asc) as PreviousHourly,
            lag(s1.ChangedDate, 1, null) over (partition by s1.emp order by s1.ChangedDate asc, s1.seq asc) as LastChangedDate,
            lead(s1.ChangedDate, 1, null) over (partition by s1.emp order by s1.ChangedDate asc, s1.seq asc) as NextChangedDate
    from setup s1
    where s1.ChangedDate is not null
)

select  hr.emp,
        cast(hr.[date] as date) as effdt,
        hr.seq,
        cast (hr.hourly as money) as hourly, 
        cast(s.LastChangedDate as date) as LastChangeDate,
        cast(s.PreviousHourly as money) as PreviousHourly
from @hrly_chg hr
left join setup2 s 
on hr.emp = s.emp
and ( 
    -- assign values to same record
    (hr.[date] = s.ChangedDate and s.seq = hr.seq)
    -- assign values to inbetween records
    or  (hr.[date] > s.ChangedDate and hr.[date] < s.NextChangedDate)
    -- assign values where hourly changes in next sequence on same day
    or  (hr.[date] = s.NextChangedDate and hr.hourly = s.NewHourly)
    -- assign values where hourly changes in previous sequence on same day
    or  (hr.[date] = s.ChangedDate and hr.hourly = s.NewHourly)
    )
order by hr.[date], hr.seq
```

**Output**

```
+-----+------------+-----+--------+----------------+----------------+
| emp |   effdt    | seq | hourly | LastChangeDate | PreviousHourly |
+-----+------------+-----+--------+----------------+----------------+
| A   | 2013-08-19 |   0 | 25.22  | NULL           | NULL           |
| A   | 2014-01-01 |   0 | 26.73  | 2013-08-19     | 25.22          |
| A   | 2014-08-19 |   0 | 31.20  | 2014-01-01     | 26.73          |
| A   | 2014-08-19 |   1 | 31.20  | 2014-01-01     | 26.73          |
| A   | 2014-12-14 |   0 | 31.20  | 2014-01-01     | 26.73          |
| A   | 2015-01-08 |   0 | 31.20  | 2014-01-01     | 26.73          |
| A   | 2015-01-09 |   0 | 31.20  | 2014-01-01     | 26.73          |
| A   | 2015-01-10 |   0 | 31.20  | 2014-01-01     | 26.73          |
| A   | 2015-01-20 |   0 | 38.33  | 2014-08-19     | 31.20          |
| A   | 2015-02-08 |   0 | 38.33  | 2014-08-19     | 31.20          |
| A   | 2015-08-16 |   0 | 38.33  | 2014-08-19     | 31.20          |
| A   | 2015-08-16 |   1 | 41.54  | 2015-01-20     | 38.33          |
| A   | 2016-01-10 |   0 | 42.37  | 2015-08-16     | 41.54          |
| A   | 2016-06-05 |   0 | 42.37  | 2015-08-16     | 41.54          |
| A   | 2016-06-05 |   1 | 45.55  | 2016-01-10     | 42.37          |
| A   | 2016-06-06 |   0 | 45.55  | 2016-01-10     | 42.37          |
| A   | 2017-03-05 |   0 | 46.23  | 2016-06-05     | 45.55          |
+-----+------------+-----+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Hi Rex, the server is down but the output and query you posted looks promising. I will try its speed when the server is up. Thank you for the suggestion.